# Turning on a salvaged computer power supply (Apple 8100 - SMP 220DB 8100 Series)

Tags: power-supply

I salvaged a power supply out of my old Mac 8100 (it's an Apple 614 0012 200W Power Supply Power SMP 220DB 8100 Series). It looks like it will be good for my hobby projects (+5v, +12v, -12v *...negative voltage? don't know why I would want that*, and +5v TRKL  *...don't know what that is. Trickle?*) It has a 110/220 input - basically your standard computer supply.

**I just don't know how to turn it on.** I ran into this once before and thought the power supply was dead rather than it being managed by a power switch.

I'm assuming that one of the wires functions as a switch when grounded but since this is using house current, I figured I would ask before resorting to trial and error. Logic would seem to be that the blue wire (in the image below) if grounded to a black wire will turn the power on. Does this sound like a good guess?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I figured it out. This may be too narrow in scope to be of use to anyone but here is what I discovered ([based on this page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2171912?start=0&tstart=0) - reproduced below).

I had foolishly thrown away the motherboard cord (hadn't even noticed it) so had no cable color reference. With trial and error using a resistor and some alligator clips, I was able to discover the electronic switch pin, the +5v trickle pin and a ground. **Note:** This is reference to the pins in the motherboard socket connector (not shown in the photo above) and not to the leads shown in the photo. Those are the power outputs.

I guess a two position toggle switch will work to toggle between the +5v pin and a ground - though I don't know if leaving the switch pin continuously powered while the supply is running is a bad idea.

[image]